# Admob ad in Listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, ads

Can someone point me in the right direction, I am trying to use Ad mob ad in the list view. I want them to come up as every 10th item. I tried some examples but they are not working with new Google play services version of Ad Mob.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you will struggle to get this to work for a number of reasons. You are much better off setting up an AdView either above or below your ListView.

Comment: They asked for someone to point them in the right direction. Having spent many hours working with both ListView adapters and Admob views I did that. And since they voted for my answer it looks like it was of benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using an adapter to "decorate" your content adapter. Take a look at [this article](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.it/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html).

Basically you have a function `isAdPosition(int position)` which tells your adapter to create
an ad if it's the 10th, 20th, ... position, or to delegate the creation of the view to your content adapter if it's not an ad position.